# Bundling responding to random query string

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

I have minification and bundling all enabled and working. I have an issue on each deployment where in lets say my script are versioned abc.js and after new deployment they are efg.js. Now when my app because of rolling deployment (new version) calls efg.js , this request goes to load balancer and it could be routed to abc.js causing the new version of app to be messed up for sometime until all boxes have the latest version.

Also one interesting thing i noticed was, the version hashed in query string can be any random string and the asp.net app responds with the JS. So in this case if i make request to /bundle/scripts/style?v=xxx.js the app reponds even though xxx is not valid. I would have expected a 404 from the asp.net application.